# converting old code to connect to web-service using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have a ASMX client application that i am trying to convert to using WCF. So i added a service reference, and it gave me a `SoapClient` class. My old code was using a class derived from `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtoco`l and it had two properites. Url and `ClientCertificates`. Are there any equivalent of these in this SoaClient class that I get in WCF world ?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to the Url property is the endpoint address which you can set through the the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574927.aspx) of your proxy object, or through the configuration (use the WCF Service Configuration Editor to edit the config). For ClientCertificates, use the [ClientCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms553830.aspx) property of your proxy object.

Here is some sample code which will get you started.

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding = basicHttpBinding;
MyServiceSoapClient myService =
    new MyServiceSoapClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(url));
myService.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(Certificate);
```

All of this can also be done through configuration rather than code, using the WCF Service Configuration Editor to set up the config file; this makes it much easier to reconfigure the service (does not require code changes).